# What adapter(s) do I need to connect a Retina MacBook Pro Thunderbolt output to a 2560x1440 NEC monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I've got a 13" Retina MacBook Pro and an NEC PA241W 2560x1440 monitor.  What adapters do I need to connect them at full resolution?

Answer (score -1):

Mini Display Port to Display Port.

http://www.colorwiki.com/wiki/NEC_PA241W_Review#VIDEO_CONNECTIONS

Thunderbolt is in effect Display Port plus more functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Just get a [Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/B/mini-displayport-to-dvi-adapter).  From there, use a DVI cable to connect to the monitor.

Comment: why? When the MBP has Thunderbolt/mini DP already & the monitor has DP already. What's the point of paying 30 bucks for an adapter plus however much for a cable when all you need is a cable?

Comment: I was not aware it had a DP connection.  99% of the monitors out there have VGA/DVI inputs, and a number of them contain HDMI inputs as well.  Also, Eric doesn't mention if he already has a DP cable or a DVI cable.  If he has a DVI cable, my solution works.  If he has a DP cable, your solution works.

That said, was a downvote truly necessary?

Comment: I don't want to get into any argument over it. I did some research, posted my answer, you didn't, & posted a more expensive answer; hence my downvote. The monitor ships with 3 cables - http://www.necdisplay.com/p/desktop-monitors/pa241w-bk?type=support

Comment: Thanks very much!  My monitor does in fact have a displayport input, so it looks like the mini DP to DP solution will be less expensive than mini DP to DVI.  And thank you for explaining that a thunderbolt output is just mini DP enhanced.  That's very useful.

Comment: BTW, I would have voted you both up, but I'm brand new on this site and I need 15 reputation to vote up!!  Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, best of luck.  If I may suggest, check into an SSD.  I had a 2010 13" MBP where I removed the optical drive, put the original 250GB rotating drive in it's place via a kit, and installed an SSD for the main boot volume.  Once you enjoy 14-second boot times, you'll wonder how you ever survived without it.  Here's the kit:  http://bit.ly/1bo3X72